# How to get my keyboard backlight back after Mountain Lion upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade, keyboard

I have a non-Unibody MacBook Pro running 10.8.2. After I installed Mountain Lion, the keyboard backlight does not light up any more. Is it a connection with the new OS, or is it a defect of my Mac?

Comment: What happens when you press F5 or F6? You may need to hold Fn (function) when doing so depending on your keyboard settings. I want you to look for [this overlay](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Kxl.png) to appear on your screen when pressing F5/F6, or Fn F5/F6.

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone, expect an OS X update to address this very soon, until then others have had success by disabling the auto dim in low light feature.

System Preferences > Keyboard > uncheck "Adjust keyboard brightness in low light".